# How to find previous month and year in golang

Tags: go

I just found AddDate() does not always works as expected.

ex:

```
mayEndDate := time.Date(2021, 5, 31, 12, 00, 00, 00, time.UTC)
finalDate := endOfMay.AddDate(0, -1, 0)
```

here
output:

- **myEndDate** = 2021-05-31 12:00:00 +0000 UTC
- **finalDate** = 2021-05-01 12:00:00 +0000 UTC

I was expecting finalDate to be in **April**.
After reading the documentation, I found out the reason.

> AddDate normalizes its result in the same way that Date does, so, for example, adding one month to October 31 yields December 1, the normalized form for November 31.

***My question:*** how to now correctly find out the last month's date from today's date?

Comment: How do you define "correct" in this case? If one month before march 30 is feb 28, and one month before feb 28 is Jan 28, then what is two months before march 30? Is it Jan 28 or Jan 30?

Comment: @BurakSerdar, I just want to know what was the previous month. ex. 
if date= 1st march 2022, then prev month & year:- feb 2022, 
if date = 1st dec 2021, then prev month & year: dec 2020, 
if date=28 feb 2022, then prev month & year: jan 2022, 

hope I am clear!

Comment: If the date is first of the month, then your code will give you the previous month. The problem is if the date >28. If you just need the previous month/year, create a new date from the given date by setting the date to the first of the month, and subtract a month.

Comment: Yes, that can be done. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Get the current month using [`Month()`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.Month), then from there it’s pretty simple to get the previous one:

```
currentMonth := mayEndDate.Month()
previousMonth := currentMonth - 1
if currentMonth == time.January {
    previousMonth = time.December
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> if date is 2021-05-31 then previous month is April 2021.

---

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func prevMonth(t time.Time) (int, time.Month) {
    y, m, _ := t.Date()
    y, m, _ = time.Date(y, m-1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC).Date()
    return y, m
}

func main() {
    endOfMay := time.Date(2021, 5, 31, 12, 00, 00, 00, time.UTC)
    fmt.Println(endOfMay)
    fmt.Println(prevMonth(endOfMay))
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/rP25ramRrZ3

```
2021-05-31 12:00:00 +0000 UTC
2021 April
```